# Laravel factory method returns invalid data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-7

In my Laravel 7 project I have a `Location` model which stores my postcodes (plz) and the name of the city (name). As you can see from my migration the `plz` field is the primary key.

The problem I'm facing is in my test, that the `plz` from my database does not match the return value from the factory method. With my other models I don't have this issue.

Maybe it is caused by the fact that I don't have an `id` field in the table as a primary key.

```php
public function test()
{
    $location = factory(Location::class)->create();
    $location2 = Location::first();

    var_dump($location->attributesToArray());
    var_dump($location2->attributesToArray());

    $this->assertEquals($location->plz, Location::first()->plz);
}
```

The console output:

```
E:\Dev\BBBB\BBBB-Laravel\tests\Feature\LocationManagementTest.php:43:
array(4) {
  'plz' =>
  int(0)
  'name' =>
  string(10) "Mechernich"
  'updated_at' =>
  string(27) "2020-10-19T19:09:04.000000Z"
  'created_at' =>
  string(27) "2020-10-19T19:09:04.000000Z"
}
E:\Dev\BBBB\BBBB-Laravel\tests\Feature\LocationManagementTest.php:44:
array(4) {
  'plz' =>
  int(52479)
  'name' =>
  string(10) "Mechernich"
  'created_at' =>
  string(27) "2020-10-19T19:09:04.000000Z"
  'updated_at' =>
  string(27) "2020-10-19T19:09:04.000000Z"
}
```

My factory:

```php
$factory->define(Location::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    $plz = random_int(10000, 99999);
    return [
        'plz' => $plz,
        'name' => $faker->city,
    ];
});
```

My migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('locations', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedInteger('plz');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->primary('plz');
    });
    // add check constraint for plz
    DB::statement('alter table locations add constraint plz_check check (plz>=10000 and plz<=99999)');
}
```

Laravel version: v7.28.4

PHP version: v.7.4.11

Database: MariaDB version: 10.4.11

Comment: did you set `$incrementing` to false on the model?

Comment: the field type `unsignedInteger` has `$autoIncrement` an false by default:
`public function Blueprint::unsignedInteger($column, $autoIncrement = false)`

Comment: did you set `$incrementing` to false on the Model? not the migration

Comment: Now it's working. thank you